# Laravel File Manager 404 error

Tags: laravel, file, http-status-code-404

I just installed Laravel file manager on my project and I don't understand why I get an `NotFoundHttpException` when I try to pop up the file manager.

I've installed it in many projects and it's the first time that I get this kind of error.

I already put the `LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider` in my providers,
and the service provider is above the `RouteServiceProvider`
I've tried to clear the route cache, to publish all files etc...

When I do php artisan `route:list` I have the correct routes with the correct middlewares,

but on my browser impossible to access the file manager,

so with the console the routes appear to be correctly registered, but the browser does not find it

any idea how to proceed ? Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

I used a pre-made code for the wysiwyg editor coming from Laravel File Manager website but the code was wrong,

Be careful in the "Integration" section, the code is not always correct with the default given configuration.

Comment: Please share your solution, if it is not sooo private.... I have a prob....